# code for CRF implementation in C++ or Matlab for images

Tags: c++, matlab, image-segmentation

I need some code for CRF implementation in C++ or Matlab for images for  segmentation problem. Which is the more appropriate code library? It will be great if it supports higher order energy terms

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I've had great success with Justin Domke's [JGMT](http://phd.gccis.rit.edu/justindomke/JGMT/). It is written in C++ and can be used from Matlab. I would recommend you look at this library first.

There are plenty of other options: [CRFSuite](http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/) which is written in C++ but easily accesible from Python and stuff.

There is also [CRF++](http://crfpp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/index.html) which is written in C++ and does have bindings for Python and Ruby.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links :) I checked JGMT, it seemed good, but it has the limitation of supporting only pairwise graphs...I want to use higher order energy terms.