# Problems with building CRFsuite bindings for python in Windows

Tags: python, crf++, crf

I use Python for named entity recognition task and I wanna use CRF. I am looking for a python implementation of CRF. I've realized that 3 implementations of CRF (StanfordNER, CRF++ and CRFsuite) has python bindings but only by CRFsuite I can train a model in python, while with CRF++ and StanfordNER, I can only try the existing models in python.

On the other hand, I have so many problems with building [CRFsuite bindings for python](https://github.com/chokkan/crfsuite/tree/master/swig/python) in windows. I found the descripition in [CRFsuite website](http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/manual.html) incomplete or maybe I can't understand it well!

I just looked through similar questions about any python implementation of CRF and noticed that people mentioned that it is easy to have access CRFsuite from python! like these two examples:

[1- code for CRF implementation in C++ or Matlab for images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211690/code-for-crf-implementation-in-c-or-matlab-for-images),

[2- Implementation of CRF in python](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38216/implementation-of-crf-in-python)

I would appreciate it if anybody tried to build these bindings in windows share the instructions with me. Or even any other suggestion about using CRF in python?

Thanks